# Collate dictionary list into a nested list

Tags: python, database, list, dictionary

It's hard to search for what I'm having trouble describing, so I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere.

I have a list of dictionaries from a cli tool (timewarrior, if you're familiar!) that I want to organize into a hierarchical structure for the purposes of printing a table, or exporting a CSV.

How that hierarchy will be generated depends on the order of a list contained in each list element, called "tags". Each list of tags contains some tracked time. I want to summarize the time spent on the hierarchy from the bottom, to the top.

Here is an oversimplified example of the data I am dealing with:

```py
data = [{"tags": ["Project A", "Task 1"], "time": 50},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2"], "time": 20},
        {"tags": ["Do a thing"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project B", "Do a thing"], "time": 50}]
```

With that data, I am hoping to create one of the follow two structures for a recursive function call:

A nested list:

```py
outcome_a = [["Project A", 70, [["Task 1", 50], ["Task 2", 20]]],
             ["Do a thing", 10],
             ["Project B", 50, ["Do a thing", 50]]]
```

Or a nested dictionary:

```py
outcome_b = {
    "Project A": {
        "time": 70,
        "sub": {
            "Task 1": {
                "time": 50
            },
            "Task 2": {
                "time": 20
            }
        }
    },
    "Do a thing": {
        "time": 10
    },
    "Project B": {
        "time": 50,
        "sub": {
            "Do a thing": {
                "time": 50
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It feels simple enough to iterate the dictionaries then iterate the tags inside. What's tripping me up is how to elegantly keep track of the time context of each element once iteration has moved past the first layer of nested data.

I obviously don't want to iterate the list ad nauseam and try to re-discover the context. The best solution I can think of is to iterate the data and somehow pass the context along to the next `tags` element. I think some sort of recursive function or reducer could to do the trick.

At this point I have hammered away a couple of free-time hours to juggle how I could go about this. I'm sure I'm over-thinking things. I am open to suggestions :)

Comment: Why dont you do it recursively?

Comment: @NachoR That's my first inclination. The part where I get tangled up is the context of the nested time values, and the checking of existing/already created nested values in the new data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're continuously accessing it, I would avoid a nested `list`.

Your `dict` result is easy enough if you utilize `dict.get`.

```
data = [{"tags": ["Project A", "Task 1"], "time": 50},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2"], "time": 20},
        {"tags": ["Do a thing"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project B", "Do a thing"], "time": 50}]

result = {}
for tags in data:
    project, *task = tags['tags']
    task_time = tags['time']
    if task:
        result[project] = result.get(project, {'time': 0, 'sub': {}})
        result[project]['sub'][task[0]] = {'time': task_time}
        result[project]['time'] += task_time
    else:
        result[project] = {'time': task_time}
        
print(result)
# {
#     'Project A': {
#         'time': 70, 
#         'sub': {
#             'Task 1': {'time': 50}, 
#             'Task 2': {'time': 20}
#         }
#      }, 
#     'Do a thing': {'time': 10}, 
#     'Project B': {
#         'time': 50, 
#         'sub': {
#             'Do a thing': {'time': 50}
#         }
#     }
# }
```

Some highlights:

This unpacks the `'tags'` key into 2 variables. If only one item exists in the `list` under that key, an empty `[]` is assigned to `task`.

```
project, *task = tags['tags']
```

We know in this branch the `'sub'` key is needed. `dict.get()` is used here to retrieve the `project` key. If it doesn't exist, a default `dict` structure is assigned to it.

```
result[project] = result.get(project, {'time': 0, 'sub': {}})
```

Since the initial value of `result[project]['time']` is set to `0`. We can continuously add on to that key.

```
result[project]['time'] += task_time
```

And finally, for single tasks, when `task` is "Falsey".

```
result[project] = {'time': task_time}
```

Edit:

For something tags size agnostic, you can use the same `dict.get` trick and us it to nest arbitrarily deep. It also has the added bonus of removing the `if` statement.

```
data = [{"tags": ["Project A", "Task 1"], "time": 50},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2", "Part 1"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2", "Part 2"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Do a thing"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project B", "Do a thing"], "time": 50}]

result = {}
for tags in data:
    project, *tasks = tags['tags']
    task_time = tags['time']
    result[project] = result.get(project, {'time': 0})
    result[project]['time'] += task_time
    current_dict = result[project]
    for task in tasks:
        current_dict['sub'] = current_dict.get('sub', {})
        current_dict = current_dict['sub']
        current_dict[task] = current_dict.get(task, {'time': 0})
        current_dict[task]['time'] += task_time
        current_dict = current_dict[task]
        
print(result)
# {
#     'Project A': {
#         'time': 70, 
#         'sub': {
#             'Task 1': {'time': 50}, 
#             'Task 2': {
#                 'time': 20,
#                 'sub': {
#                     'Part 1': {'time': 10},
#                     'Part 2': {'time': 10}
#                 }
#             }
#         }
#      }, 
#     'Do a thing': {'time': 10}, 
#     'Project B': {
#         'time': 50, 
#         'sub': {
#             'Do a thing': {'time': 50}
#         }
#     }
# }
```

Comment: This is a lot more terse than anything I've come up with so far, so thank you for that! It only allows a relationship 2 levels deep, and I'd like to go to 3. Ideally it would be "tags size agnostic", but I can get a better start from here.

Comment: @trevdev I added a version that can nest arbitrarily deep. I modified the input a bit to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: Well done! Thanks for sharing this method.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post my own answer. Thanks again to @Axe319 for helping me shake this down.

I wanted to see the nested list happen, so here it is:

```py
DATA = [{"tags": ["Project A", "Task 1"], "time": 50},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2", "Part 1"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project A", "Task 2", "Part 2"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Do a thing"], "time": 10},
        {"tags": ["Project B", "Do a thing"], "time": 50}]

ROWS = []


def update_row_data(rows, task):
    levels = task["tags"]
    time = task["time"]
    level, *nested = levels
    row = -1

    for i, t in enumerate(rows):
        if t[0] == level:
            row = i
            break

    if row > -1:
        rows[row][1] += time
    else:
        rows.append([level, time, []])
        row = len(rows) - 1

    if nested:
        next = {"tags": nested, "time": time}
        rows[row][2] = update_row_data(rows[row][2], next)

    return rows


for entry in DATA:
    ROWS = update_row_data(ROWS, entry)

print(ROWS)
```